# Prove $x=y ⇔ x≤y ∧ x≥y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{K}$ if $ \mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. A subset $\mathbb{K}^{+}$ is an ordered field if: $x$ is either $x∈\mathbb{K}^{+}$, $x=0$, or $−x∈\mathbb{K}^{+}$. Secondly, if $x,y∈\mathbb{K}^{+}$, then $x+y,x⋅y∈\mathbb{K}^{+}$.

Prove $x=y ⇔ x≤y ∧ x≥y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{K}$,   if $ \mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

For "$\Rightarrow$"

Since $x=y$, it is $x\geq x$ and $x\leq x$ which means by definition that:

$x\geq x$, if $x-x\in \mathbb{K}^+\cup \{0\}$  and

$x\geq x$, if $x-x\in \mathbb{K}^+\cup \{0\}$

which is true.

Is that correct and how do I do the other way "$\Leftarrow$"

Comment: With the condition 'For all $x$, either $x \in \mathbb{K}^+$ or $x=0$ or $-x \in \mathbb{K}^+$,' is that an exclusive or? 
If not, then the definition isn't correct because it would allow every field to be so-called ordered with $\mathbb{K}^+ = \mathbb{K}$. 
If it is an exclusive or (or you've got more axioms that would let you prove that) then that's where the proof of the other direction comes from.

Comment: Your last line with equations should have $x \le x$ but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For the other direction you have $y-x \in \Bbb K^+ \cup {0}$ and $x-y=-(y-x) \in \Bbb K^+ \cup {0}$.  You should be able to show that it must be that $y-x=0$